# form return strange character

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

My template is

```
<form method="GET" action="....">
                    <input type="submit" name="golfsite" value="1net" />
                    <input type="submit" name="golfsite" value="Golfagora" />
                    <input type="submit" name="golfsite" value="Juchi" />
</form>
```

views.py is

```
def affiliate(request, golfsite=None):

    golfsite = golfsite or request.args.get('golfsite')


    ......
```

On debug mode console, if I type 'golfsite' to check what is golfsite, it returns `u'1net'` or `u'Golfagora'` or `u'juchi'`. What is happening? What is `u`, Why doesnt it return `1net` or `golfagora` or `juchi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting Unicode strings, which is normal. This is not a problem. Django has decoded incoming form data to Python unicode strings based on the encoding used. This is normal behaviour.

Please do read up on Python and Unicode in the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) to avoid future confusion.

Comment: i want to compare the golfsite with '1net' string, how can I do it by the way?

Comment: @John: Yes, for ASCII strings that is perfectly possible. You can generate Unicode literals too, to avoid automatic encoding problems: `u'1net'` is a Unicode literal. For ASCII values `'1net' == u'1net'` is True.